# Pop-up alert on image click.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question on how you spawn a pop-up when an image is clicked. I want a pop up to be some sort of alert. Here is my current html code I am working with:

```
<div>
 <div class="Zipshare">
    <span class ="projectIcons">
      <a href="">
        <img src="images/photostack.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="caption"><h6>Photostack</h6></span>
</div>
```

I have seen other posts describing how to spawn an alert view but don't know how to link it to an image. I was thinking a doing it through some sort of href link but can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have code that you tried that didn't work? Could you please post that?

Comment: For more info, see [alert()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) and [.addEventHandler()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the onclick attribute

```
<img src="images/photostack.png" onclick="alert('Hello World')" alt="" />
```

Or use jQuery:

```js
$( "#img" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Hello World jQuery" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="img" src="images/photostack.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this...  Here is a short one inline with your html:

```
<img src="images/photostack.png" alt="" onclick="alert('you clicked it')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pictureRc() {
alert("You right clicked that image!")}
```

This is my function I used in js and the html looked like this:

```
<img src="pic.jpg" oncontextmenu="pictureRc()">
```

So when you right click it makes an alert. I know this is late but for anyone finding this thread later thought it might help!

just change the oncontextmenu to onclick for left click